Bad session in Isabelle
I am trying to run Incompleteness from afp-2019-08-19 on Isabelle2023. When I open the ROOT file
chapter AFP

session Incompleteness (AFP) = HereditarilyFinite +
  description "The Incompleteness Theorems"
  options [timeout = 2400]
  sessions
    Nominal2
  theories
    Goedel_I
    Goedel_II
  document_files
    "root.bib"
    "root.tex"

I get the following errors:
Bad session "HereditarilyFinite"⌂ 
Bad session "Nominal2"⌂

Googling the error returned no useful results. Initially, I assumed that Isabelle cannot find the projects HereditarilyFinite and Nominal2, but they are in the same directory as Incompleteness. I probably just don't know how to search for/enable sessions, since no sessions defined with another session work. (Note: sessions defined with "HOL", "HOL-Light" and other presumably in-built sessions do work.)
This error seems strange to me, as I assumed that the downloaded AFP archive should work out-of-the-box.

Two questions: 1. Have you used isabelle components -u to register your AFP copy with Isabelle/jEdit as described in https://www.isa-afp.org/help/ ? 2. Is there a particular need to use AFP 2019 and Isabelle 2023? (Your life might become easier if you just use the most current versions of both.)

@BenjaminBisping Thank you, this solved my problem. Consider posting your comment as an answer. What tripped me up was probably that I focused specifically on the Bad session error, coupled with the almost complete absence of any simple online documentation on it.

You're right, it's really quite hard to get those imports right! Reading another question around the same problem (https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/4285/setup-autocorres-and-use-with-isabelle-for-c-programs) prompted me to actually write a proper answer. Hope it helps somebody in the future!

Bad session means that Isabelle is not able to resolve a reference to another session in a session ROOT-file. (A similar problem from within a theory file will yield Bad theory import.)
The fix is easy: If you install a copy of the AFP, you need to let your Isabelle installation know about it by registering it as a component like this:
isabelle components -u MY_PATH_TO_AFP/thys

(This is also explained in the AFP help.)
If you have multiple Isabelle versions installed, be sure to invoke the right __/Isabelle20__/bin/isabelle!
The isabelle components -u command will register the component path in the list under ~/.isabelle/Isabelle20__/etc/components. This makes the sessions defined in the ROOT file of the directory (and those referenced through a ROOTS file), accessible by imports.
When referring to such registered component sessions from your theories, you will usually need to use imports qualified by the session name. In the example, a theory header would need to read ...imports Incompleteness.Goedel_I or so. If the session name contains a - or other special characters, you have to wrap the qualified name in quotes, e.g. ... imports "HOL-Library.Extended_Nat" ....
